# How to access variable between classes

Tags: c++

Just have a question. I am trying to display a filename in a message box. This file name is part of a full path. I need to set the path using a Set method in CChooseDirDlg class and call this in SecondDlg class using a Get method. Both classes are declared as friends but are in different files. However, the message box is returning nothing. Any ideas? Thankyou for your time...

ChooseDirDlg.h

```
class CChooseDirDlg : public CDialog
{
// Construction

    friend class SecondDlg;


public:

    CString sPath;
```

ChooseDirDlg.cpp:

```
void CChooseDirDlg::SetPath(CString path){

    path = m_DirTree.GetCurrentDir(); //find path
    sPath = path; 
}

CString CChooseDirDlg::GetPath(){

return sPath;

}
```

SecondDlg.cpp:

```
void SecondDlg::OnOK() 
{

    CChooseDirDlg dlg;


    dlg.SetPath(path); // set path 

    dlg.GetPath(); // get path


    char drive[_MAX_DRIVE]; 
    char dir[_MAX_DIR]; 
    char fname[_MAX_FNAME]; 
    char ext[_MAX_EXT]; 

// Split path to isolate filename 

_splitpath(dlg.GetPath(), drive, dir, fname, ext);


AfxMessageBox(fname);

}
```

Comment: If you dont call `SetPath` before `GetPath` what should it return? You put too much unrelated code and actually it is not clear, where is the problem

Comment: Yeah I don't follow what the problem is.. Can you show all your code and why not just pass a string of the file name to the other class...

Comment: CChooseDirDlg dlg; instantiates a new object that knows nothing about what you've done in other instances.  you will need to at least call dlg.SetPath()

Comment: Apologies I know its kinda messy but theres a lot I'm working on I'm trying to keep it concise... the SetPath() method does not seem to set the path in the SecondDlg class. The compiler is telling me at SetPath(path) that path is undeclared...

Comment: You are mixing up some things here. Q: "How to access variable between classes?" A: "Use a public getter methods". I dont see any need for friends. And anyhow your sPath is public (it should not be) so you do not even need the getter method...

Comment: your message box is blank because fname is blank,  because _splitpath() is passed a blank by your call to dlg.GetPath(), because you have never called dlg.SetPath()  -- a debugger would clearly show this

Comment: @T.Malo how could I pass a string of the file name to the other class...?

Comment: Something like this... use #include <string>
string ClassNameA::passFileName(){return fileName; }
string ClassNameB::receiveFileName(string fileName){ ur code }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code don't show where you set the path, but I'm going to presume  that this is done somewhere that is not inside the `OnOk` scope.

The line:

```
CChooseDirDlg dlg;
```

in your `OnOk` method means that you are creating a local instance of the `CChoseDirDlg` class.

This instance does not share the value of member variables (if they are not static) with other instances of the class, so if you call `SetPath` on another instance, the `dlg` instance in the `OnOk` scope will not have the data.

Comment: Oh now I understand... how can I access the data from an instance of the class, if at all?

Comment: In some way you will have to retrieve the instance that you call `SetPath` on. Possibly passing it into the `OnOK` function?

Comment: Is that even possible? Apologies man I'm new to this language... and if it is, how could I retrieve that instance without losing the file path data...?

Comment: This is not a language issue. Passing arguments into functions/methods exists in pretty much every language there is. Helping you in this case is hard due to a couple of reasons. I don't have all of the code, I don't even know where you create the instance where you set the path, nor do I know your level of experience in programming. I would personally recommend searching on google for  how functions and especially function parameters works, or ask your teacher or textbook if you are taking a class! And please, if my answer was 'correct' mark it. Good luck!

Comment: Alright man thanks...I think I figured it out...I need to declare the variable as static... thanks again